# sudo apt-get install not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, apt, dpkg

when I try `apt-get install upgrade` this error shows up:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavresample-dev : Depends: libavutil-dev (= 6:11.9-1~deb8u1+rpi1) but it is not installed
 libopencv-highgui-dev : Depends: libavcodec-dev (>= 0.svn20080206) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libavformat-dev but it is not installed
                         Depends: libswscale-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

when i run `apt-get -f install` i get this as response:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't install anything using `apt-get install` right now and I think it may have to do with my dpkg version.

Comment: Why do you suspect dpkg?  Have you downloaded a version from some strange place?

Comment: this error line is why: ´E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)´, no i did not @joan